# cortana SetPhraseListAsync in uwp strange behavior

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, cortana

I'm trying to update programmatically the phraselist in a UWP app, I followed the cortana uwp sample and this code doesn't work:

```
   VoiceCommandDefinition commandDefinitions;

                    if (VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstalledCommandDefinitions.TryGetValue("xxxCommandSet_en-us", out commandDefinitions))
                    {

                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("favouriteStringList not null ");
                            await commandDefinitions.SetPhraseListAsync("favourite", favouritesList);
}
```

when I try with windows phone 8 approach it works

```
  Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.VoiceCommandSet commandSetEnUs;

                if (Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.VoiceCommandManager.InstalledCommandSets.TryGetValue("xxxCommandSet_en-us", out commandSetEnUs))
                {
                    await commandSetEnUs.SetPhraseListAsync(
                      "favourite", favouritesList);
                }
```

here there is my VCD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="xxxCommandSet_en-us">

    <AppName> xxx </AppName>
    <Example> Book a yyy in my favourite home </Example>

    <Command Name="bookyyyInFavourite">
      <Example> Book a yyy in my favourite home </Example> <!--Book xxx a yyy in my favourite home-->
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> book [me] a yyy in my favourite {favourite} </ListenFor>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="ExplicitlySpecified"> book [me] {builtin:AppName} a yyy in my favourite {favourite} </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Booking a yyy in my favourite {favourite} </Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>

    <PhraseList Label="favourite">
      <Item>home</Item>
      <Item>work</Item>
    </PhraseList>

  </CommandSet>

</VoiceCommands>
```

do you have any idea why this happen?
thanks

Comment: I tested it by my side, it works fine, why you said it doesn't work? Can you please show your vcd file?

Comment: yup, that's awkward :) I added the VCD. thanks

Comment: OK, I didn't find any problem in your vcd file, so why you said it doesn't work? What is the behavior?

Comment: after I update the phraselist programmatically for example with "gym", I got no exceptions, but when I ask Cortana "Book a yyy in my favorite gym" in the first case doesn't work, it makes a web search, in the second case open the app properly :)

Comment: You have two blocks of c# code, I tested your first code in an UWP app, my OS version is 10586.218, tested with local machine, strange thing, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: yup I understand, 'll try on another machine, thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome! ;) Sorry I didn't help much.

Comment: you helped, at least I know that the code should work :)